# Text goes goes into separate lines when using a percentage padding

Tags: html, css, forms, pixel

I have a small problem in html forms. When I give the following css,

```
.row .section-1 label {/* Formatting all section-1 labels */
      padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
      margin: 3px 0 0 0;
      display:block;
```

}

This is the output that I get :

[image]

However when I edit the css to put padding in the form of a percentage:

```
.row .section-1 label {/* Formatting all section-1 labels */
      padding: 0 40% 0 80%;
      margin: 3px 0 0 0;
      display: block;
}
```

This is the output I get :
[image]

I want to use percentages, however I want the look in the first image. Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use percentages instead?

Comment: please post your html-markup for that form and any other relevant css-rules, too. otherwise it's almost impossible to say whats wrong with your code. (does this work in other browsers or do they all have the same problem?)

Comment: the problem is there only in chrome and IE, but in firefox it looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're padding too much on the left of your label element:

```
.row .section-1 label {/* Formatting all section-1 labels */
      padding: 0 40% 0 80%;
      margin: 3px 0 0 0;
      display: block;
}
```

The definition of CSS padding in percentage is as follows:

> Defines a padding in % of the containing element

So it's adding 80% of the label elements width as a padding. In your original fixed padding example you're only setting 10px padding on the left.